# using tf.data or queues CNN text classification by tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, text-classification, tensorflow-datasets

I used CNN-Text Classification base on this github link https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf, While my dataset is too large with 10000 documents(Size: 120M).

For Efficient performance, I want to **change the evaluation set to use a smaller subset of my data, or use Tensorflow queues or tf.data to read data sequentially.** Now I don't know how can I solve this issue? and witch **.py** project in this package has to be changed?

Thanks.

Comment: You can just split your data into two parts, right? one for training, the other (like 5%) for evaluation. In your eval, you only run your eval binary on the 5% split so make sure you specify positive_data_file and negative_data_file to  point to your eval split files.